# How to use D3.js to visualize JSON returned from my app's GET request

Tags: javascript, express, d3.js, handlebars.js, nvd3.js

I'm building an Express.js app to communicate with a [third-party API](http://strava.github.io/api/v3/activities/) and visualize parts of the returned JSON.

One of the relevant routes is:

```
req = require 'request'
...

app.get '/activity', (request, response) ->
  options =
      url: baseurl + '/activities/111008284'
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ac0bd2c2b020c232ebe2c560'}

  req options, (error, res, body) ->
    if !error and res.statusCode == 200
      data = JSON.parse body
      response.render 'activity', data
```

here `data` is the JSON data I want. In my my `activity.hbs` I can interact with the JSON to, for example, create a table without any problems.

```
<table class="overview">
      <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Distance (Meters)</th>
      <th>Elapsed Time (Seconds)</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{distance}}</td>
      <td>{{elapsed_time}}</td>
      <td>{{calories}}</td>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

How can I get D3 to read in the same `activity` JSON object? Do I have to use `D3.xhr`?

```
<script>
d3.xhr("localhost:3333/activity", function (error, data) {
d3. #logic to interact with JSON
nv.addGraph()

</script>
```

or is there an easier way?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `activity.hbs` at all? Because if not, then the most appropriate thing to do is call `response.json(data)` (instead of `render()`) and then get the data using `d3.json("localhost:3333/activity", function ...`.

Comment: yes, `activity.hbs` is my view for the route `activity`. I have expressed configured with `app.set 'view engine', 'hbs'
app.engine '.html', hbs.__express`.

Comment: Right, but the question is why do you need to respond with HTML in the first place? This is a request for data, so why not respond with json -- without rendering the hbs template into HTML at all? My comment showed how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your data parsed as a Javascript object, you don't need any special functions to read it -- just use the data object directly, the exact same as you would use it if you had created it with a d3 function.  Take the code the callback function that you would have used within `d3.json(filename, callbackFunction)`, and instead call it from your other GET routine, passing it the data object that you created as  `data = JSON.parse(body)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I run include a Javascript script calling D3 from within a Handlebars template? 

I've tried a simple `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8">
  d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
          .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
          .enter().append("p")
          .text(function(d) { return "I’m number " + d + "!"; });

  </script>`

from within my `view.hbs`, but nothing appears when the view is rendered.

Comment: `<script>` elements should have [*either* a `src` property *or* internal script code, not both](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).  You need one script tag for the d3 library, then a second script tag for your code.  Beyond that, I don't know anything about Handlebars.  If you're still having problems, ask a separate question with the appropriate tags.